# bashrc function to create a folder every month and switch XDG_DESKTOP_DIR to it

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, desktop-environment, desktop, xdg-user-dirs

I am actively using desktop, so files and folders rapidly accumulate on desktop.

I need a `bashrc` way that it checks month on the first day then creates a directory with month name, finally sets it `desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

- you can set up a cronjob, that runs a script of your daily: `man crontab`
- in the script you:

  - create a folder for the last month on your desktop: `man mkdir` and [How do I assign last month's date (year and month only - 2016-07) as a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301526/how-do-i-assign-last-months-date-year-and-month-only-2016-07-as-a-variable)
  - you run a `find` that finds all files that are older than one month. Here's an example of a `find` that deletes (`rm`) older files -
    you'll need to adapt it to `mv` older files into the created directory: [Delete files older than X days +](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194863/delete-files-older-than-x-days)

Answer (score 1):

First manually change the config by yourself for this month and run this for the next month.

```
change_desktop()
{
month=$(date +%B)
last_month=$(date '+%B' --date '1 month ago')
mkdir /home/$USER/Desktop/$month
sed -i "s|Desktop/$last_month|Desktop/$month|" ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs 
}
```

This will create the current month's folder in Desktop and then look for the last month in the config and change it to the current month.

I don't know how to run this piece automatically using the `~/.bashrc`, but you can setup a cron job for the user and let it run every month. Just add this code snippet to a file called `change_desktop.sh` add the following code :

```
#!/bin/sh
change_desktop()
{
month=$(date +%B)
last_month=$(date '+%B' --date '1 month ago')
mkdir /home/$USER/Desktop/$month
sed -i "s|Desktop/$last_month|Desktop/$month|" ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs 
}
change_desktop
```

Then create a cron job for the current user like this :

```
0 0 12 * * sh /home/$USER/change_desktop.sh
```

If however you want to do this manually, you can add the first code snippet to the `~/.bashrc` and run `change_desktop` in your terminal and it will do the job for you, as it is already a function in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it require to check if current month's folder exists?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to concoct my own script.

```
new_desktop="$HOME/Desktop/$(LC_ALL=tr_TR.utf8 date +'%B-%Y')"
if [ ! -d "$new_desktop" ]; then  
   mkdir "$new_desktop" 
   xdg-user-dirs-update --set DESKTOP "$new_desktop"
   nautilus -q
fi
```

But I doubt about how reliable it is.

Comment: The script looks nice to me! I allowed myself to improve it a bit: indented it, corrected the line break, used a variable `$new_desktop` instead of repeating the same expression over and over...